# Why most non-invasive current sensors have a minijack at the other end?

Tags: sensor, connector, current-sensing

If I search on google for non-invasive current sensor and click on the images tab, in most cases, I see a minijack at the other side of the wire.

What is the reason for this? Is this minijack supposed to be connected somewhere specific?

Comment: sure it need to be plugged into an actual meter. What you see is just a probe.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can you please provide a web link to such a meter? I m trying to find a single image with this jack being plugged somewhere and I fail :)

Comment: I can find mostly DIY projects too. This jack is probably the most common analog input connector on different development boards.

Comment: `What is the reason for this?` ... because your google search returns hits to similar kinds of websites ...... `Is this minijack supposed to be connected somewhere specific?` yes, a TRS mini plug

Answer (score 1):

Many Non invasive current sensors come without a minijack

The minijack is manufacturer specific. Use an amplifier made by the same manufacturer to convert the readout to something sensible (for example sparkfun sells [this sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005), with this [breakout board)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13679).

In the case of current transformers the output is a voltage that can be [amplified and monitored](https://blog.openenergymonitor.org/2009/06/non-invasive-current-sensing-method/) with an ADC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean something like this:

[image: Seeed Studio Current Sensor]

The minijack is for connecting the sensor to something that is going to read the data, like a microcontroller or similar.

Comment: Yes, but I can't find any example of this jack being connected somewhere. Can you provide a common device to which I can connect it?

Comment: No, this is not a "consumer product" that you can just purchase and plug into something.  If you need a complete non-invasive ammeter, please consider something like: https://www.amazon.com/Fluke-323-True-RMS-Clamp-Meter/dp/B00AQKIEXY

Comment: Perhaps if you explained more about what exactly you're attempting to do some better suggestions could be offered.